# When is Windows Forms the correct choice vs WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, windows-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF versus Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-windows-forms)

I presume that WPF is intended to eventually replace Windows Forms altogether, but for now, they are both shipping.

My question is, when is one more appropriate than another? Should we be leaving Windows Forms to legacy and creating new Windows Clients in WPF only?

Disclaimer: I'm not generally a Windows client developer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909/when-creating-a-new-gui-is-wpf-the-preferred-choice-over-windows-forms