# Is "aim to develop WPF unless you need to drop back to Windows Forms" the general advice?

Tags: wpf, winforms

Is the general advice re windows apps technology to develop in "aim to develop WPF unless you need to drop back to Windows Forms".

I known there are some specific pros/cons for particular scenarios/requirements (e.g. assumptions about what version of .net is available on the desktop) however I'm just after overall general advice.  Like is Windows Forms on the way out so, if all else is equal, you should be learning/building in WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO already has lot of discussion on this issue.

> - [Is it better to use WPF over WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640633/is-it-better-to-use-wpf-over-winforms)
> - [When is Winforms the correct choice vs. WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf)
> - [Will WinForms be deprecated in favor of WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913417/will-winforms-be-deprecated-in-favor-of-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on lots of factors (even if they all else is equal), in particular presentation.  Eg. If you are distributing the interface through citrix, windows forms may be a more robust solution.  What about your user base? They may be more familiar with the windows forms controls and would like a "comfortable" familiar interface.
They're just a couple of thoughts.