# How to make DirectX Control partially transparent on C# Form

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, directx, transparency

I have a Windows Form with an image as a background; and I also have a user control which I've added to the form, and renders itself using directx.  However, I want the directx UserControl (directx scene) to render partially transparent so that I can see the image background of the form.

I have the source code to the managed directx user control, but I just don't know enough about directx to make it so the entire scene renders semi-transparent.  Does anyone know how I would go about achieving this?

Note:  I'm using C#/VS '08/Managed DirectX

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in Windows Forms as you'll run into '[airspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx)' issues. There are a few posts which cover this ([granted they point you to use WPF and D3DImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640633/is-it-better-to-use-wpf-over-winforms)).

Comment: thanks for the link sixlettersvars, i'll take a look.  Although it is looking like you're right in that it may not be possible to do with windows forms.

Answer (score 1):

not sure but, maybe this will help...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Nildo%20Soares%20de%20Araujo/TransparentControls11152005074108AM/TransparentControls.aspx

Comment: Joe, I tried applying the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style to the user control but it didn't work.  Thanks though.

Comment: yea, it was a longshot...but, thought it was a good reference for you.