# C# for UI, c++ for library

Tags: c#, c++, mfc

I have a numerical library coded in C++.

I am going to make a UI for the library. I know some MFC. So one solution is to use MFC and make a native application.

The alternative is C#. I know nothing about C#. But I think it should be easy to learn.

Some tutorial for mixed programming of C++ and C# would be very helpful to me.

Thanks!

Yin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using Windows Forms or WPF via C# for your GUI.

Take your numerical library, and use C++/CLI to make a .NET wrapper for it.  This makes it trivial to use from C# (it looks like any other C# library).

I highly recommend [Nishant Sivakumar's C++/CLI articles](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=20248) on CodeProject for learning about C++/CLI and how to wrap C++ libraries.  They're fairly well written.

MSDN is a good reference for how to use [Windows Forms from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Write your GUI in C# using [WinForms or WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf), and call your native code through [Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx).

Instead of P/Invoke, you might want to consider C++/CLI to make a .NET wrapper for your native library.

IMHO using C# is MUCH more easier than MFC, so you are on the right track.

Comment: P/Invoke is difficult if it's a true C++ library.  You almost have to have a C API for your library to use it.  C++/CLI is much more expressive.

Comment: Depends on the interface of his C++ library, certainly. If it is simple and short, P/Invoke will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# very easily to make the UI.  You'll need to write a simple wrapper class to call your unmanaged dll, but that is straightforward.  check out the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx) on that subject

Answer (score 0):

Go with C#. MFC is somewhat dated, so if you need to learn something - go for newer technology, do not waste your time with MFC.
I'd go for WPF, learning curve is rather steep, but its fun.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html).  You can write the core part of your code in C++ as a dll, then have a C# UI link against it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source to your C++ numerical library, you can modify it to compile as C++/CLI then you can link to it just like any other .NET library.  It shouldn't require a large amount of work to modify the source with #defines for C++/CLI conditional compiling.