# WPF or win forms?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have to make an application that looks like UI same to same how can i make i have to do it in c#.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Decyclone said, it can be done either way, but I agree with both Decyclone and Stefan that WPF is definitely the way to go.  Personally, I feel like it has a lot more versatility, and like Stefan said, Microsoft didn't seem to have WinForms at the top of their "to do" list in recent years, to say the least.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf) is another SO question that explains the advantages of when to use which.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703681/winforms-vs-wpf) is another SO question that explains the differences/advantages of each.
As is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I can make a statement based on this single screenshot but in general I would say: if you create a new project from scratch, use WPF/Silverlight instead of WinForms.

MS didn't really invest in WinForms the past few years...

Answer (score 2):

Looking a the `UI`, I would prefer `WPF`. Not that it can't be done with `WinForms`, but it will be a lot easier with `WPF`.

After setting up a basic layout, all you will need to do is apply custom styles/themes/templates to these controls.