# MS Access 2007 forms for .net developers

Tags: .net, ms-access

I need to work with Access to create a form based solution - does anyone know of any good quickstarts / tutorials aimed at .net programmers for this?  Everything I have found is aimed at Access beginners where all I need is a foot up to save time trawling through each control etc.

Comment: With older versions of access, I found the VBA level documentation to be a good place to start when looking for the kind of information you'd need.  With 2007, as an experienced programmer, you can probably make it just by poking around.

I say this because you're not likely to find what you need.  Many .NET developers more or less thumb their nose at Access as something that's beneath them.  So there are probably more tutorials to tansition TO .net than away from it

Comment: I agree with Russel to say that your situation is quite .. unusual. Though it is not relate dto your question, could you espose us how you came into this situation?

Comment: I realise it is probably slightly unusual - a friend of mine has several Access databases at work which he wants to try putting some forms on - having worked with him in a previous life where I was a VB developer I ended up being the defualt person he asked for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a major point -- until you've used Access like a novice, you won't understand how little programming you need to do to get things done.

Do the beginner tutorials -- just do it.

You'll discover that a huge proportion of the stuff that requires code in other development environments is point-and-click simple in Access. After that, go to something more advanced. You won't get any value out of advanced Access tutorials/books unless you fully understand how to use its design facilities interactively, and one of the chief sources of frustration for programmers coming to Access from other platforms is that they just don't understand the default approach in Access, which is using bound data (suitably filtered at runtime, which is something the novice tutorials won't teach you).

Comment: good points by David. I highly suggest starting with the beginner tutorials and goggling for a good VBA reference book. Access is rather simple once you get over the learning curve; being a developer should get you there pretty quickly.

Comment: That makes sense - VBA etc is no problem, it is the default codeless approach that I need to get to grips with

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some basic/conceptual info on Access forms and their management [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400/best-way-to-test-a-ms-access-application). This could be a start for your work. There are many other resources available on stackoverflow, often hidden in answers. Do not hesitate to browse the ms-access questions.