# Should I re-purpose subform controls on one form or just create multiple forms?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In my office of 65 people, I want to create a "portal" for all the employees out of a single .accdb file. It will allow each employee to navigate to a new "screen" from a dropdown menu.

Should I use a single form with plug-and-play subform controls in order to centralize the VBA code, or should I just use different forms?

I'm thinking it would be nice to have one form with plug-and-play subform controls. When the employee selects a new "screen", the VBA just sets the `SourceObject` property of each subform control and then re-arranges the subforms based on the layout of the selected "screen".

For instance, we currently use a couple of Access database forms to enter and review errors that we find in our workflow system. So in this scenario, to review the errors I would just say

```
SubForm1.SourceObject = "Form.ErrorCriteria"
SubForm2.SourceObject = "Form.ErrorResults"
```

And then I would just move them into place (these values would be pulled dynamically based upon the "screen" selected):

```
SubForm1.Move WindowWidth * 0.05, WindowHeight * 0.05, WindowWidth * 0.9, WindowHeight * 0.2
SubForm2.Move WindowWidth * 0.05, WindowHeight * 0.25, WindowWidth * 0.9, WindowHeight * 0.65
```

So this creates a small header section (`SubForm1`) on the form where I can select the criteria for the errors I want to see (data range, which team committed the error, etc) and then I can view the errors in the much larger section below the header (`SubForm2`) that holds the datasheet with the results.

I can propogate events up to the main form from the `ErrorCriteria` and `ErrorResults` forms that are now bound to the subform controls. That will help me to use the basic MVC design pattern for VBA described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347000/2363207). I can treat the main form as the view, even though parts of that view are buried in subform controls. The controller only has to know about that one view.

My problem comes when the user selects a new "screen" from the dropdown menu. I think it would be nice to just re-purpose the subform controls, like so:

```
SubForm1.SourceObject = "Form.WarehouseCriteria"
SubForm2.SourceObject = "Form.InventoryResults"
```

And then just move/resize those subforms to the appropriate layout for the "Inventory" screen.

This approach seems to make the user interface design cleaner in my mind because you basically only ever have to deal with one main form that acts as a template and then you plug in the values (the `SourceObject` properties) into that template.

But each time we change the "screen", we have a totally different "Model" behind the scenes and a new "View" too according to the MVC design pattern. I wonder if that would clutter up the MVC VBA code behind the scenes, or if the VBA code itself could be modularized too (possibly using Interfaces) to make it just as adaptable as the user interface.

What is the cleanest way to do this from both a User Interface perspective, and from a VBA perspective. Use one main form as template where other forms could be swapped in and out as subforms, or just close the current form and open a new form when the user selects a new "screen" from the dropdown menu.

Comment: First, I sure hope you have a frontend/backend setup if you have 65 people! To give a suggestion on the form interface, it depends on the number of controls/complexity of the form you have. We developed a 'report interface' that depending on the role of the user, they could see anywhere from one to 20 filters (controls), thus used one form with a 'map' table. How complex is your form?

Comment: Yes, it is a split database. How are you using that map table? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Map Table has fields: ID (PK), ReportName, CtlName, CtlOrder, CtlTop, CtlLeft, SkipLabel (Bool), CtlRecordSource. All ctls hidden unless used by report. When user selects report from combobox, list of fields retrieved from map table and the form is altered.

Comment: Interesting, never thought about putting that data into a table. Have you run across any issues with that approach?

Comment: Not a one! In our case, our controls were all the same height, so it was simple to calculate the 'tops' to place in the table. Most of the 'lefts' were the same since we had listed filters in a column - except for some 'from/to' pairs. Performance was great (I believe we turned off painting till finished).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Feel free to make this an answer and I'll accept it. I am curious too if you had to do anything special to tie the newly re-purposed controls to their events/VBA. For example, if I have a button and I re-purpose it, then I may have different events to trigger from the new button. As I mentioned in the question I have tried some aspects of this scenario but I don't yet feel comfortable with it. If you have any pointers on working with these newly re-purposed controls in terms of events or VBA code, I would be interested in hearing them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a brief description of one way to 'repurpose' or reformat a form for several uses. Re your question of changing the VBA code, a simple solution would be to check a label value or some value you set in the control, then call the appropriate VBA subroutine.

We had over 100 reports available, each with their own selection criteria/options and we did not want to create a unique filter form for every report. The solution was to identify the selection options available by report, identify the logical order of those options, then create a table that would present the options to the user.

First, we created the table: ctlReportOptions (PK = ID, ReportName, OptionOrder)
Fields: ID (Int), ReportName (text), OptionOrder (Int), ControlName (text), ControlTop (Int), ControlLeft (Int), SkipLabel (Y/N), ControlRecordsourc(text)
Note 1: ID is not an AutoNumber.

Next we populated with records that would define the view the user would see.
Note 2: Using an ID of zero, we created records for EVERY field on the report so we could always redraw for the developers.

Then we created the form and placed controls for every possible filter. 
We set the 'Default Value' property to be used as our default.

Some of the controls:
ComboBox to select the report name. Add code for Change event as follows:

```
Private Sub cboChooseReport_Change()
Dim strSQL      As String
Dim rs          As ADODB.recordSet
Dim i           As Integer
Dim iTop        As Integer
Dim iLeft       As Integer
Dim iLblTop     As Integer
Dim iLblLeft    As Integer
Dim iLblWidth   As Integer
Dim iTab        As Integer
Dim strLabel    As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    ' Select only optional controls (ID <> 0); skip cotrols always present.
    strSQL = "SELECT ctlRptOpt.ControlName, 'lbl' & Mid([ControlName],4,99) AS LabelName, SkipLabel " & _
                "From ctlRptOpt WHERE (((ctlRptOpt.ID)<>0)) " & _
                "GROUP BY ctlRptOpt.ControlName, 'lbl' & Mid([ControlName],4,99), SkipLabel;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordSet
    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Me(rs!ControlName).Visible = False      ' Hide control
        If rs!skiplabel = False Then            ' Hide Label if necessary
            Me(rs!LabelName).Visible = False
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    iTop = 0
    iTab = 0

    ' Get list of controls used by this report; order by desired sequence.
    strSQL = "select * from ctlRptOpt " & _
                "where [ID] = " & Me.cboChooseReport.Column(3) & _
                " order by OptionOrder;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordSet
    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic

    If rs.EOF Then      ' No options needed
        Me.cmdShowQuery.Visible = True
        Me.lblReportCriteria.Visible = False
        Me.cmdShowQuery.left = 2000
        Me.cmdShowQuery.top = 1500
        Me.cmdShowQuery.TabIndex = 1
        Me.cmdReset.Visible = False
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        GoTo Proc_Exit              ' Exit
    End If

    ' Setup the display of controls.
    Me.lblReportCriteria.Visible = True
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!skiplabel = False Then
            strLabel = "lbl" & Mid(rs!ControlName, 4)
            iLblWidth = Me.Controls(strLabel).Width
            Me(strLabel).top = rs!ControlTop
            Me(strLabel).left = rs!ControlLeft - (Me(strLabel).Width + 50)
            Me(strLabel).Visible = True
        End If

        iTab = iTab + 1         ' Set new Tab Order for the controls
        Me(rs!ControlName).top = rs!ControlTop
        Me(rs!ControlName).left = rs!ControlLeft
        Me(rs!ControlName).Visible = True
        If left(rs!ControlName, 3) <> "lbl" Then
            Me(rs!ControlName).TabIndex = iTab
        End If

        If Me(rs!ControlName).top >= iTop Then
            iTop = rs!ControlTop + Me(rs!ControlName).Height          ' Save last one
        End If

        ' If not a label and not a 'cmd', it's a filter! Set a default.
        If left(rs!ControlName, 3) <> "lbl" And left(rs!ControlName, 3) <> "cmd" Then
            If Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue = "=""*""" Then
'                Me(rs!ControlName) = "*"
            ElseIf left(Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue, 2) = "=#" And right(Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue, 1) = "#" Then
                i = Len(Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue)
'                Me(rs!ControlName) = Mid(Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue, 3, i - 3)
            ElseIf Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue = "True" Then
'                Me(rs!ControlName) = True
            ElseIf Me(rs!ControlName).DefaultValue = "False" Then
'                Me(rs!ControlName) = False
            End If
        Else
            If Me(rs!ControlName).top + Me(rs!ControlName).Height >= iTop Then
                iTop = rs!ControlTop + Me(rs!ControlName).Height          ' Save last one
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    If Me.cboChooseReport.Column(1) <> "rptInventoryByDate" Then        ' It's special
        Me.cmdShowQuery.Visible = True
        Me.cmdShowQuery.left = 2000
        Me.cmdShowQuery.top = iTop + 300
        iTab = iTab + 1
        Me.cmdShowQuery.TabIndex = iTab
    Else
        Me.cmdShowQuery.Visible = False
    End If
    Me.cmdReset.Visible = True
    Me.cmdReset.left = 5000
    Me.cmdReset.top = iTop + 300
    Me.cmdReset.TabIndex = iTab + 1

Proc_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Error_Trap:
    Err.Source = "Form_frmReportChooser: cboChooseReport_Change  at Line: " & Erl
    DocAndShowError     ' Save error to database for analysis, then display to user.
    Resume Proc_Exit    ' Exit code.
    Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.
    Resume
End Sub
```

lblReportCriteria: We displayed the final set of filters so when users complained of nothing showing on the report, we asked them to send us a screen print. We also passed this text to the report and it was printed as a footer on the last page.

cmdReset: Reset all controls back to their default values.

cmdShowQuery: Executes the running of the report

```
Private Sub cmdShowQuery_Click()    
Dim qdfDelReport101             As ADODB.Command
Dim qdfAppReport101             As ADODB.Command
Dim qdfDelReport102             As ADODB.Command
Dim qdfAppReport102             As ADODB.Command
Dim qryBase                     As ADODB.Command
Dim strQueryName                As String
Dim strAny_Open_Reports         As String
Dim strOpen_Report              As String
Dim qdfVendorsInfo              As ADODB.Command
Dim rsVendorName                As ADODB.recordSet
Dim strVendorName               As String
Dim rsrpqFormVendorsInfo        As ADODB.recordSet

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboChooseReport.value) And Me.cboChooseReport.value <> " " Then
        strAny_Open_Reports = Any_Open_Reports()
        If Len(strAny_Open_Reports) = 0 Then

            If Me.cboChooseReport.value = "rptAAA" Then
                BuildReportCriteria                 '
                If Me.chkBankBal = True Then
                    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAAA_Opt1", acViewPreview
                Else
                    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAAA_Opt2", acViewPreview
                End If
            ElseIf Me.cboChooseReport.value = "rptBBB" Then
                If IsNull(Me.txtFromDate) Or Not IsDate(Me.txtFromDate) Then
                    MsgBox "You must enter a valid From Date", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Date"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If IsNull(Me.txtToDate) Or Not IsDate(Me.txtToDate) Then
                    MsgBox "You must enter a valid To Date", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Date"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                Me.txtStartDate = Me.txtFromDate
                Me.txtEndDate = Me.txtToDate
                DoCmd.OpenReport Me.cboChooseReport.value, acViewPreview
            ElseIf Me.cboChooseReport.value = "rptCCC" Then
                If Me.txtVendorName = "*" Then
                    gvstr_VendorName = "*"
                Else
                    Set rsVendorName = New ADODB.recordSet
                    rsVendorName.Open "selVendorName", gv_DBS_Local, adOpenDynamic

                    Set qdfVendorsInfo = New ADODB.Command
                    qdfVendorsInfo.ActiveConnection = gv_DBS_SQLServer
                    qdfVendorsInfo.CommandText = ("qryVendorsInfo")
                    qdfVendorsInfo.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                    strVendorName = rsVendorName("VendorName")
                    gvstr_VendorName = strVendorName
                End If
                DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFormVendorReport", acViewPreview
            Else
                BuildReportCriteria
                If Me.cboChooseReport.value = "rptXXXXXX" Then
                ElseIf Me.cboChooseReport.value = "rptyyyy" Then
                    On Error Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "temp_xxxx"
                    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
                    Set qryBase = New ADODB.Command
                    qryBase.ActiveConnection = gv_DBS_Local
                    qryBase.CommandText = ("mtseldata...")
                    qryBase.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                    qryBase.Execute
                End If
                DoCmd.Hourglass False
                DoCmd.OpenReport Me.cboChooseReport.value, acViewPreview
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "You cannot open this form/report because you already have a form/report(s) open: " & _
                    vbCrLf & strAny_Open_Reports & _
                    vbCrLf & "Please close the open form/report(s) before continuing."

             strOpen_Report = Open_Report
             DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, strOpen_Report
             DoCmd.ShowToolbar "tbForPost"
        End If
    Else
         MsgBox "Please Choose Report", vbExclamation, "Choose Report"
    End If

    Exit Sub

Error_Trap:
    Err.Source = "Form_frmReportChooser: cmdShowQuery_Click - Report: " & Nz(Me.cboChooseReport.value) & "    at Line: " & Erl
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then   ' MsgBox "You chose not to open this report.", vbOKOnly, "Report cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Err.Number = 0 Or Err.Number = 7874 Then
        Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.

    ElseIf Err.Number = 3146 Then   ' ODBC -- call failed -- can have multiple errors
Dim errLoop     As Error
Dim strError    As String
Dim Errs1       As Errors

    ' Enumerate Errors collection and display properties of each Error object.
    i = 1
      Set Errs1 = gv_DBS_SQLServer.Errors
        Err.Description = Err.Description & "; Err.Count = " & gv_DBS_SQLServer.Errors.Count & "; "
        For Each errLoop In Errs1
            With errLoop
                Err.Description = Err.Description & "Error #" & i & ":" & " ADO Error#" & .Number & _
                        " Description= " & .Description
                i = i + 1
            End With
        Next

    End If
    DocAndShowError     ' Save error to database for analysis, then display to user.
    Exit Sub
    Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.
    Resume
End Sub
```

Function to build a string showing all of the selection criteria:

```
Function BuildReportCriteria()
Dim frmMe           As Form
Dim ctlEach         As Control
Dim strCriteria     As String
Dim prp             As Property
Dim strSQL          As String
Dim rs              As ADODB.recordSet

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    strSQL = "select * from ctlRptOpt " & _
                "where ID = " & Me.cboChooseReport.Column(3) & _
                " order by OptionOrder;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordSet
    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic

    If rs.EOF Then
        strCriteria = "     Report Criteria:  None"
    Else
        strCriteria = "     Report Criteria:  "
    End If

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set ctlEach = Me.Controls(rs!ControlName)
        If ctlEach.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctlEach.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            If ctlEach.value <> "*" And ctlEach.Name <> "cboChooseReport" And ctlEach.Name <> "cboLocCountry" Then
                strCriteria = strCriteria & ctlEach.Tag & " = " & ctlEach.value & " , "
            End If
         End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    If Me.chkOblBal = -1 Then
        strCriteria = strCriteria & "Non-zero balances only = Yes"
    Else
    'return string with all choosen criteria and remove last " , " from the end of string
        strCriteria = left$(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 3)
    End If
    fvstr_ReportCriteria = strCriteria

    Set ctlEach = Nothing

    Exit Function
Error_Trap:
    If Err.Number = 2447 Then
        Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.
    End If
    Err.Source = "Form_frmReportChooser: BuildReportCriteria  at Line: " & Erl
    DocAndShowError     ' Save error to database for analysis, then display to user.
    Exit Function
    Resume Next         ' All resumption if debugging.
End Function
```

Finally, each report had it's own query that would filter based on the values in the controls on this form.

Hope this helps. If you are curious about any of the weird things you see, let me know. (i.e. we always used line numbers in the code (I deleted before posting) that allowed us to identify exact line where code fails)

Comment: Why ADOB with MS Access? DAO is recommended and much faster. ADODB does have its place, but not always.

Comment: We migrated from Access to SQL Server, thus the ADO stuff  :)  I agree with DAO and use it as my first choice!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It will take me some time to work through it but it addresses the exact problem I was struggling with.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Not linked tables? :(

Comment: My explanation may bounce around a bit... very large and complex application deployed to 70+ countries; all developed with DAO... I got assigned weeks after it rolled out to try and solve performance issues. Big delay due to network speeds to the server... so one item of hundreds was to 'make static' (i.e. make local) any table that users couldn't update, including this table. Later needed to move to SQL server, so I wrote code to automatically change *all* code from DAO to ADO... thus this guy fell victim  :)